# Gradle Sync (SDK) issue with Android Studio

Tags: java, android, gradle, sdk, dependencies

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
mavenLocal()
flatDir {
    dirs 'libs'
}
}
android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'

//firebase

// Displaying images
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0' // adding database 
dependency to SDK
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

These are the gradle sync errors i am receiving.

Error:(37, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design:24.2.0

Error:(38, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0

Can someone please advise me what needs to be changed to get this running. It was working till i updated Android Studio.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I figured it out, as of March there was a new repository update

So I simply changed

```
buildToolsVersion '24.0.1'
```

I changed the build version to

```
buildToolsVersion '25.0.2' //this is actually the latest as of 12/4/17
```

Then changed the dependencies to that version from

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
```

To

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
```

Now i have no errors and my gradle actually builds, I hope this is useful to someone who may encounter this as its only new

Answer (score 0):

Change the

```
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
```

To

```
buildToolsVersion '24.2.0'
```

I hope its help you!

Comment: Now i get this , Error:Failed to find Build Tools revision 24.2.0

Comment: any other suggestions ?